# numpy external interfacing: when to require OWNDATA

Tags: numpy, cython, ctypes

If I want to interface from cython code to a numpy ndarray, clearly I will want a C_CONTIGUOUS array to make life easier.

Under what circumstances however would I need to ensure OWNDATA is set?

Answer (score 1):

NPY_OWNDATA is best used when the memory block is being allocated in the C code and passed to the Cython code (likely via a callback).  In this case if you want Numpy to begin reference counting and automatically deallocate the memory block when the reference count goes to zero then you add the NPY_OWNDATA flag.

If you're using a ring buffer or other construct in the C code where the Python code is only going to be using the memory temporarily while it does it's calculations and will then notify the C code that it can re-use the memory block then you definitely don't want NPY_OWNDATA because Numpy will free the memory that the C code is expecting to still have.

There's a good discussion of this here:

http://blog.enthought.com/python/numpy-arrays-with-pre-allocated-memory/#.VxpQTjArKUk